# show exception error message in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I'm trying to get exception message like this and pass to `FileUpload` view like this in controller class

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = ex.Message;                
        }

        return RedirectToAction("FileUpload", "FileUpload",ViewBag.Error);
    }
```

In `FileUpload` view page I'm trying to show that error messge like this

```
@ViewBag.Error
```

But I cannot see any error message here

**EDIT**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FileUpload()
    {
       ..
       return View(p);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        ..
        return RedirectToAction("FileUpload", "FileUpload");
    }
```

Comment: Show your `FileUpload()` method - does it have a parameter to accept the error message, and are your then adding that value to `ViewBag` in that method?

Comment: Show FileUpload Action

Comment: Do need to pass that ViewBag value to FileUpload , `get` method also ?

Comment: You don't need to pass `ViewBag.Error` with `RedirectToAction()` method, you just need to put your `@VeiwBag.Error` in your view, and it will show the error message.

Comment: @SeM thats how I'm currently done

Comment: You can also use TempData to pass on the data between some action methods which is even better than passing value as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to accept that message in **FileUpload** action then again assign it to viewbag to get data in page.

```
   string exmsg="";
    try
    {
    //....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     exmsg = ex.Message;                
    }
    return RedirectToAction("FileUpload", "Controllername", new { errormsg = exmsg });
    }

[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(string errormsg)
    {
       ViewBag.Error=errormsg
       return View(errormsg);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("FileUpload", "FileUpload", new { errorMessage = ex.Message});                
            }
```

and the Get method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FileUpload(string errorMessage)
{
   @ViewBag.Error = errorMessage;
   . . .
   return View(p);
}
```

and I believe that the second argument of `RedirectToAction("FileUpload","FileUpload")` is your Controller name.